# Flutter uint8 (bgr8) Raw Image Data Convert to Picture

Tags: image, flutter, dart, flutter-image, uint8list

I was able to get the video streaming, but it has a lot of static. I think there's something wrong with my bitmap header (I think it is missing). Could someone please tell me if there is anything I can include from the raw data I'm receiving for the bitmap header? Thank you!

Example raw image data received:

I/flutter ( 9674): {encoding: bgr8, height: 480, header: {stamp: {secs: 1599095871, nsecs: 933816910}, frame_id: bottom_camera_front, seq: 4766}, step: 1920, data: 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

Comment: `Uint8List.fromList` takes a list of integers as its input. You are giving it a list of strings (or more specifically, a list of _one_ string). You need to actually decode the data string into a byte array before you can work with it.

Comment: And even then you'll likely need to stick a BMP header on it for image to understand it. It'll need to know the width, height, pixel format and depth etc.